# Parse.com Object P has no method '_mergeFromObject'

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, before-save

so this happend:

before_save triggered for Products for user xcx:

Input: {"original":null,"update":                             {"cost":227.27,currentStock":0,"isTakeAway":false,"markup":0,"name":"Laptop","price":250,"priceExcludingTax":227.27,"reOrderPoint":0,"recommendedOrder":0,"taxGroup":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"TaxGroup","objectId":"SJtku9hHXX"},"type":"simple"}}

Result: TypeError: Object P has no method '_mergeFromObject'

Does anybody know why this happend? I've searched for this error but found nothing.  and it's not from my before save code, it's something from parse.